# can any one suggest a good math function in javascript to round integer?

Tags: javascript, math

i have to round the value from `2.3456789` to `2.345` .

After `.` there must be three number only remaining should be removed

Comment: This page outlines a couple of different approaches:
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/round.html

Comment: `Math.round(2.3456789 * 1000)/1000`? BTW, rounding 2.3456789 to 3 decimal places should give you 2.346, not 2.345.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `value.toFixed(3)`, but that will round up to 2.346.

You could just `parseInt(value * 1000) / 1000` if you really don't want to round.

You may need to ensure value is a number first:

```
value = new Number(value)
```

Now if `value` is user input, it's possible that it might now be `NaN` (Not a Number).

You can't do `if(value == NaN)` to check, `NaN` is never equal to anything (not even itself), you must use the `isNaN(value)` function.

Comment: OP doesn't ask about NaN function. Why are you posting it here ? OP clearly says, that input is a number i.e 2.3456789

Comment: @roadrunner: because .toFixed() is a function on the Number object.  That's why, defensive coding.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Math.round()`.

This will round to 3 decimal places.

```
var result=Math.round(2.3456789*1000)/1000  //returns 2.345
```

---

In fact, the formula to round any number to `x` decimal points is:

1) Multiple the original number by `10^x (10 to the power of x)`.
2) Apply `Math.round()` to the result.
3) Divide result by `10^x`.

Comment: I don't understand why you would do this over .toFixed(), and Math.round(2.3456789*1000)/1000 returns 2.346, not 2.345.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript 1.5+ introduced **Number.toFixed(n)** and **Number.toPrecision(n)** - pick one depending on what you need.

**Number.toFixed()** lets you specify the number of digits after the decimal point (padded if necessary).

```
(2.3456789).toFixed(3) = "2.346"
(3).toFixed(3) = "3.000"
```

**Number.toPrecision()** lets you specify the number of significant figures.

```
(2.3456789).toPrecision(4) = "2.346"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Math.floor(2.3456789 * 1000) / 100`. This might result in floating-point errors, so it might be a better idea to just do it via string functions

```
var parts = String(2.3456789).split(".");
var out = parts[0] + "." + parts[1].substring(0, 3);
```

Of course, the second method may choke on numbers with exponents.

Comment: There's certainly merit in using strings to avoid floating point errors.  One could just stick to integers though if calculations are required (e.g. instead of working in centimeters, work in millimeters).

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to round the number

```
// Arguments: number to round, number of decimal places

function roundNumber(rnum, rlength) {

  var newnumber = Math.round(rnum*Math.pow(10,rlength))/Math.pow(10,rlength);

  retrurn parseFloat(newnumber); // Output the result to the form field (change for your purposes)

}
```